# In blackberry devices will Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID change frequently

Tags: android, blackberry

I developing android application, I'm interested to run my application in blackberry devices.

In my application im getting `android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)` for my settings. While running in blackberry will the android id change frequently?